# When do we use custom httphandlers and httpmodules

Tags: asp.net

Handlers and modules certainly help us tap the pipleline but when do we know for a particular functionality should be incorporated as handlers or modules.

I have looked for following answers on msdn

```
For handlers its 
1) RSS feeds
2) Image Handler to resize images

For modules its
1) Security as custom authentication
2) Statistics and Logging
3) Custom headers or footers
```

Is this all modules and handlers can provide?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After reading about custom handlers and modules, after reading about the http application pipeline,
I have understood that modules and handlers can be a great way to attach functionality to the pipeline and filter requests via modules and handlers.